# "I am joined by two guests today" or "I am joined with two guests today"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, prepositions, idiomatic-language, passive-voice

1. I am **joined by** two special guests today.
2. I am **joined with** two special guests today.

I often hear the first one on TV and it makes sense. But, today I have seen the second one **"joined with"** being used by a native British speaker. So, it sounded different to me and I got confused.

So, I wonder which one is correct?

Comment: I have taken thee liberty of reversing the order of your two example sentences to match the meaning of your question. This edit may not show up for a few minutes.

Comment: Also I think an active form *Guest X is joining/joins me today* is much more common.

Comment: Although this doesn’t appear to be common usage in Britain either, preposition usage often varies from dialect to dialect. Often, more than one usage is correct in the same dialect.

Comment: Either they weren't a native speaker or they were making a joke.  Hard to know without context.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are **joined with** two other people, you are physically fixed together like conjoined triplets, or maybe stuck using glue. The 'native British speaker' may have been using English carelessly.

Comment: Well done Michael Harvey. It was exactly like you said. There were 3 of them. They were filming a youtube video and they were sitting physically fixed fogether to fit into the camera.

Comment: @yunus sitting close to each other is not enough. To be "joined with," you have some sort of attachment, like being glued together. You would generally only see that use in a few places: machinery, physical systems, and marriage spring to mind.

Comment: So it sounds like they weren't using English carelessly, they were making a visual joke based on the distinction between "joined by" and "joined with".

Comment: @yunus - if somebody expressed curiosity or surprise that I and a relative, friend or spouse were not together absolutely all the time, or that I did not have a detailed and up-to-date knowledge of their doings, I might say "We're not joined at the hip".

Comment: @yunus If you share the video with us, we can better judge if the native British speaker is joking or making a mistake.

Comment: @fectin Surgical procedures can also accomplish this. Human Centipede, for example.

Comment: @theonlygusti Here is the video link. Just listen between 0:50-0:55 seconds. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TuvxaSZtuLU

Comment: @yunus he just made a mistake

Comment: As fectin pointed out, _joined with_ is also used in the figurative sense (ie not physically) in the case of _joined in marriage_. Well, mostly not physically...

Comment: @PabloH - I see a UK newspaper said "Invited guests joined together to mark the launch of The Co-operative Funeralcare's newly refurbished funeral home in Lower Holyhead Road, Coventry" which has raised an odd picture in my mind's eye.

Answer (score 5):

The copula followed by a past participle often constitutes the passive voice, especially when followed by "by". Here, "I am joined by two special guests today" is a passive voice version of "Two special guests join me". The "by" is introducing a noun phrase that is performing the action. "I" is grammatically the subject, but is the recipient of the action. If we replace "by" with "with", then "two special guests" is no longer the performer of the action, but rather is the indirect object; the sentence is a passive voice version of "[Unspecified actor] joins me with two special guests", which makes it sound like "I" and "two special guests" are both the recipient of the action.

It is, however, understandable that in spoken speech, someone would use "with". They may have been thinking of something along the lines of "I am with two guests" and combined it with "I am joined" incorrectly.

Comment: Acccumulation, that is also right. This sentence is from a youtube video, in which one youtuber invited 2 other youtubers. He is grateful that they joined him. So he sees himself and the other two (guests) as equal characters of the video: I think he said "joined with" to simply mean "I" and the "two special guests", which is exactly what you described.

Comment: "I have two guests, today." seems to me a way to avoid all this trouble. Or even, "Two guests join me today."